# EditText cursor position

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set EditText in xml file as `android:gravity="top"` and `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` with some text data.

The issue now here is that the Cursor is always shown at the end of the first line, whereas i want it to be at the start of the first line.

How to do this?

SOLUTION:

```
editText.requestFocus(); 
editText.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `EditText.setSelection(int index)`

Comment: done myself. This works

You need to set

editText.requestFocus();
editText.setSelection(0);